Next.js 14 API Route Works Locally but Returns 404 in Production
I have a Next.js application with the following setup:

Next.js Version: 14.2.8
Node.js Version: 20.9.0
Couchbase SDK: 4.4.1

My API route is located at:
src/app/api/translations/route.ts
The API works perfectly in the local development environment. For example:

http://localhost:8082/api/translations?lang=en returns the expected result.
Even on the production server (via SSH), accessing http://localhost:3000/api/translations?lang=en works as expected.

However, when I try to access the API via the public URL in production (e.g., http://example.com/api/translations?lang=en), I get the following error response:
{
  "error": "ERR001",
  "id": "b3b632e0349fa8fd3b5ca9fa4e578fd624617fb2ffbcef5aa6c6a029ac0e0d6f",
  "message": "No handler found for GET /api/translations",
  "source": "No handler found for GET /api/translations"
}

Code for the Route
Here's the implementation of the GET and PUT handlers in route.ts:
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../../utils/couchbase';

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const { translationsCollection } = await connectToDatabase();
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  const lang = searchParams.get('lang');

  if (!lang) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Language parameter 'lang' is required" }), {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  try {
    const result = await translationsCollection.get(lang);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(result.content), { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error fetching translation:', error);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: `Translation Not Found: ${error.message}` }), {
      status: 500,
    });
  }
}

export async function PUT(req: Request) {
  const { translationsCollection } = await connectToDatabase();
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  const lang = searchParams.get('lang');
  const body = await req.json();

  if (!lang || !body) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "Missing 'lang' parameter or request body" }), {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  try {
    await translationsCollection.upsert(lang, body);
    const updatedDoc = await translationsCollection.get(lang);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(updatedDoc.content), { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error updating translation:', error);
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ message: `Translation Update Failed: ${error.message}` }),
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

Steps I've Tried

Verified that the server is running and accessible.
Tested the API locally on the production server (localhost:3000), and it works.
Checked the file location: src/app/api/translations/route.ts.
Confirmed the build and deployment process completed without errors.
Tested removing node_modules and .next folders, then rebuilding and restarting the app.

Environment Details

Reverse proxy: Possible Nginx configuration, but I’m not sure if this could interfere.

SSL: The public URL uses HTTPS.


Question
What could cause the API route to work locally (on both development and production servers) but return a 404 error when accessed via the public URL? Are there any known issues with routing, proxy setups, or deployment configurations in this case?

I looks like your host is not translating local host to base URL. Try using your IP instead of you host name https://123.456.78.90:443 see if you API works. also check the .env file for "NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL" .

Yes, I can access my API using the IP address. Thank you for your help. I checked the server and found that I already have an .env file, but I will update it to include NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=site_url and then test the results. I'll provide an update once it's done. Thanks again!

@Mehrwarz I can access the api with ip adress. Am I should set the NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL with ip address ? Something like :
loadPath: ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL || ''}/api/translations/?lang={{lng}},

I prefer to set it to your host name. In case of changing the ip address it will still work. You can change the starting port and host name to your public host name in next JS configuration it should help you too.
